# NullReferenceException while retrieving RGB-code & adding to array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, class, bitmap, rgb

**Dear StackOverflow**

I am writing an algorythm that creates a "checkerboard image" (imgOutput) from another image (imgInput), like [this](http://www.inf.ufsc.br/~visao/khoros/html-dip/c2/s10/front-page.html) example.

What it does is checking every pixel of the image (500x500 pixels) one by one and devide the picture in 2500 boxes of 10x10 pixels each. I already wrote the algorythm to calculate the average RGB colors, not to draw the image yet. This is the code:

```
    public class PixelMatrix
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;
        public int R;
        public int G;
        public int B;
    }

    public class RGBMatrix
    {
        public int R;
        public int G;
        public int B;
    }

public Bitmap fncRasterize(Bitmap imgInput)
        {


            Bitmap imgOutput = new Bitmap(imgInput, 500, 500);
            imgOutput.Save("test.bmp");
            PixelMatrix[] arrWindows = new PixelMatrix[2500];
            RGBMatrix[] arrRGB = new RGBMatrix[100];

            Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(imgOutput);


            int WindowCount = 1;
            int PixelCount = 1;

            int WindowX;
            int WindowY;

            int PixelX;
            int PixelY;

            int avrgR = 0;
            int avrgG = 0;
            int avrgB = 0;

            int tempcounter = 0;


            for (WindowY = 1; WindowY <= 50; WindowY++)
            {

                for (WindowX = 1; WindowX <= 50; WindowX++)
                {
                    PixelCount = 1;
                    avrgR = 0;

                    for (PixelY = 1;  PixelY <= 10; PixelY++)
                    {
                        for (PixelX = 1; PixelX <= 10; PixelX++)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("R:" + imgOutput.GetPixel(1, 1).R + " G:" + imgOutput.GetPixel(1, 1).G + " B:" +imgOutput.GetPixel(1, 1).B);

                            arrRGB[PixelCount].R = (int)imgOutput.GetPixel((WindowX * 10 - 10 + PixelX), (WindowY * 10 - 10 + PixelY)).R;
                            arrRGB[PixelCount].G = (int)imgOutput.GetPixel((WindowX * 10 - 10 + PixelX), (WindowY * 10 - 10 + PixelY)).G;
                            arrRGB[PixelCount].B = (int)imgOutput.GetPixel((WindowX * 10 - 10 + PixelX), (WindowY * 10 - 10 + PixelY)).B;

                            // This is just to test
                            tempcounter = +tempcounter;
                            lblProgress.Text = tempcounter.ToString();
                        }
                    }

                    for (int tempx = 1; tempx <= 100; tempx++)
                    {
                        avrgR = +arrRGB[tempx].R;
                        avrgG = +arrRGB[tempx].G;
                        avrgB = +arrRGB[tempx].B;
                    }
                    arrWindows[WindowCount].R = (avrgR / 100);
                    arrWindows[WindowCount].G = (avrgG / 100);
                    arrWindows[WindowCount].B = (avrgB / 100);

                    WindowCount = +1;

                }
            }




            return imgOutput;

        }
```

Now when the algorythm starts running I get a NullReferenceException error on this line:

```
 arrRGB[PixelCount].R = imgOutput.GetPixel(tempR.X, tempR.Y).R;
 arrRGB[PixelCount].G = imgOutput.GetPixel(tempG.X, tempG.Y).G;
 arrRGB[PixelCount].B = imgOutput.GetPixel(tempG.X, tempG.Y).B;
```

While the line above it (the Messagebox statement) flawlessly returns the RGB values. Could someone please explain to me why this is? This is really frustrating.

Comment: are 'imgOutput' field initialized?

Comment: So stick a debug on it and examine the line. No need for you or us to guess.

Comment: I am able to save it, as you can see on the line 
imgOutput.Save("test.bmp");

Answer (score 1):

You never created the `RGBMatrix` objects in `arrRGB`, so the `R` `G` and `B` properties don't exist yet. That's where the `NullReferenceException` is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

You declare an array that has 100 slots to contain elements of type RGBMatrix.
But you have to create each of these elements and assign an instance to the correct slot before trying to access the property of the instance.

```
for (PixelX = 1; PixelX <= 10; PixelX++)
{
    MessageBox.Show("R:" + imgOutput.GetPixel(1, 1).R + " G:" + imgOutput.GetPixel(1, 1).G + " B:" +imgOutput.GetPixel(1, 1).B);

    arrRGB[PixelCount] = new RBGMatrix();   // This create the instance

    arrRGB[PixelCount].R = (int).....
    arrRGB[PixelCount].G = (int)....
    arrRGB[PixelCount].B = (int)....

    // This is just to test
    tempcounter = +tempcounter;
    lblProgress.Text = tempcounter.ToString();
}
```

or the other way

```
RGBMatrix mx = new new RBGMatrix();   
mx,R = = (int).....
....
arrRGB[PixelCount] = mx;
```

Comment: If I declare these elements in the for loop, can I still access it outside of the loop? (but in the same sub)

Comment: You declare and initialize an element (meaning you have a memory space reserved for an instance of RGBMatrix). Then you choose one of the 100 slots allocated and set its value to the pointer to the memory space allocated. This memory remains available till you have a valid reference active. In this case, after the loop the arrRGB maintain the refeerence and so you could still access the original RGBMatrix created at every loop cycle.

Comment: I'm so sorry to bother you with this and the answer is probably so obvious, but this is my first program in c#.

So this code works but then when the loop is finished and goes to this code: avrgR = +arrRGB[tempx].R; it gives me that same nullreferenceexception error. Why is that?

Comment: Array index start at zero and end at Count-1, So your declaration of arrRGG[100] should use an index starting at zero and ending at 99.